# update multi value dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, immutability, multivalue

I am trying to update a specific value in a two-dimensional dictionary where each set of key holds several values. My script is somewhat along these lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
mylist=['a', 2, 3, 4]
mydic = {}
mydic[mylist[0]] = mydic.get(mylist[0], {})
mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]] = mylist[2], mylist[3]
print mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]][0]
```

> > > 3

```
mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]][0] += 1
```

> > > TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

What goes wrong here and how should I instead update a specific value in a multi value dictionary? My actual list of key values are much longer than this example, so updating the entire key is not really a practical option...

Comment: tuples cannot be modified - immutable.

Comment: Use a list instead of a tuple: `mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]] = [mylist[2], mylist[3]]`

Comment: Thanx for the swift replies. @hagubear I realise that tuples are immutable, I just don't get why this single value is regarded as a tuple..? If I try to run >mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]][0].update(4) I get >>> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'update'. So now it's suddenly an integer..?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanx, I'll try to use a list setup.

Comment: @user3595396    You can always evaluate what type you are getting before using update(4) method. Also, list doesnt have any update method. It has append and remove though. :). Try and read the python documentation for list, tutple, set, and dict to know which methods are there for your use.

Comment: @hagubear Got it now - the dictionary value is an integer when I read it out, but when I try to update it it's an element in an immutable tuple. Got it working using a list.

Comment: @user3595396     FYI - unless you haven't got this already, try `numpy` to see if it helps your purpose - go for it! numpy is not a standard python module (won't come with your installation), but it is currently getting quite popular for numeric array/list based processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the error because you are trying to modify a tuple:

```
>>> a=(2,4)
>>> a[0]+=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

As suggested by jonrsharpe's comment, if you want to be able to modify only some value, use a list instead of a tuple:

```
>>> mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]] = [mylist[2], mylist[3]]
>>> print mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]]
[3, 4]
>>> mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]][0] += 1
>>> print mydic[mylist[0]][mylist[1]]
[4, 4]
```